# Incrementing "whitespace" for "5" times will cause an error?

Tags: java, string, char, whitespace, increment

There is an assignment in which I have to increment every index in a string by an amount set by user to generate a new name.

in other words:

key in your name: 
helen lee 
key in integer to increment: 
1 
new name: gfmfo!mff

thus, making the every index in "helen lee" to increment by 1.

Here's the problem. 
Java treats each index in a string as a character. Even whitespace. 
So when I increment "**whitespace*" by 2, it will produce "@".

BUT

When I increment a whitespace by 5, an error will occur. (should produce "%"). 
Is there any other way to increment whitespace by 5 without invoking an error?

this is my code:

```
    String alpha = " ";
    int integer = 0;

    System.out.println("Question 1: ");
    Scanner alphaInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Please enter your name. "); 
    alpha = alphaInput.nextLine();

    Scanner intInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many cycles to cycle your name: ");
    integer = intInput.nextInt();

    int stringIndex = alpha.length();
    char newName; 

    System.out.printf("Your new name is: "); 
    for(int i = 0; i < stringIndex; i++)
    {
        newName = (char) (alpha.charAt(i) + integer); 
        System.out.printf("" + newName);
    };
```

Comment: Side note: you do not need to instantiate new `Scanner`s every time you ask for input. Just re-use the old ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use `System.out.printf`. That method interprets `%` as special value, and expects more data. You should use `System.out.print` (without f) instead. For more details see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) of `printf`.

Comment: wow thanks! it worked! didnt know theres a difference between printf and print. Again thanks a bunch!